# node red on raspberry pi 4 trying to use the i2c scan node but it returns 3 address which are not what i am connected to?

Tags: node.js, node-red, i2c, raspberry-pi4

Started using node red to make a better interface than tkinter, all is going good but i am trying to now connect node red to show devices connected to my i2c bus, i am using the i2c scan node which shows 3 devices connected to my i2c bus at address 39,72,and 73, but my devices are connected to 27,48,and 49.  i have
ads1x15.ads1015 connected to 0x47
ads1x15.ads1015 connected to 0x48
gpio expander   conneccted to 0x27

any ideas why i am seeing the wrong numbers on the ic2 scan in node red compared to i2cdect -y 1 in the terminal window on the rasberry pi4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers from the node are right, it's just that they are in base 10 not base 16

```
0x27 = 39
0x48 = 72
0x49 = 74
```

Comment: Thanks for that the demo i had seen had showed them as hexadecimals which is why i was confused.